# How can i pass dynamic value through Referer URL for HTTP Header Manager in jmeter3.0?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

**My referer url for My listener request:** http://***.***.*.***:****/ecloudbaseweb//app/managecourse?courseid=815
[image]

**Referer url in Http Header Manager**

[image]
In the above url, the course id dynamic value.

**My scenario:**

Step1: I have updated course id for dynamic parameter and updated details for regular expression extractor for manage course http request

Attachment for your reference:
[image]
[image]

In this configuration, How can i set dynamic values through Referer URL for HTTP Header Manager in jmeter3.0.?

Kindly give me a solution for this scenario

Thanks,
Vairamuthu.

Dear sir,

I have updated, your comments and after changes the below issue occurred..please verify the attachment..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use values captured using Regular Expression Extractor in Header manager also, the same way you use in samplers.

Refer the screen shot:
[image]

Note: I observed that courseId (AA) is captured in **78 manageCourse** request and used in the same request. This might cause in **failure** as you have not captured the value yet, you can't use it. You need to keep the Regular Expression Extractor in earlier requests than 78, might be under **77 newCoursecreate**.

In Jmeter, First sampler is processed, and then the post processor. So, keep the Regular Expression Extractor (post processor) in the sampler (HTTP request), in which response the value (courseID) you want to retrieve is present.

Comment: Dear sir, I have updated ${AA} instead of courseid=815, But, the below error is showing  in referer url http://***.***.*.**:****/ecloudbaseweb//app/managecourse?courseid=courseid="                                                                                 So, kindly help me

Comment: you should only replace 815 by ${AA}. it looks like courseid=${AA}. Use debug sampler to check whether your regular expression extractor is capturing 815 value or not (in View Results Tree). By the way, I can't access the URL, share the screen shot that shows the error.

Comment: file:///home/local/IGSTDEV/vairamuthu_m/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202016-09-27%2015:10:32.png

Comment: First of all, tell me whether 815 (courseid) is a DYNAMIC value generated by Server? If Yes, then you should keep Regular Expression Extractor under the HTTP sampler in which 815 is returned by server. This is called Co-relation.

Comment: If 815 is a value send by user (like username and password for login), you have to do parameterization using CSV DATASET CONFIG (refer to Jmeter docs on usage), but not Regular Expression Extractor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124281/discussion-between-naveen-and-vairamuthu).